# Letter with ' (and correct spacing)

Tags: spacing, symbols, kerning, letterspacing

I am struggling with a problem I can't even name properly: I'm writing an article about an object A as well as its slightly different variant A'. I am wondering what character/symbol and/or spacing magic I need for the '.

I started by simply using ' but this gives me an pretty nasty space between the A and the '. Then I tried to correct that with `A\kern-0.1em'` Unfortunately this is not consistent as things get stretched around to fill the page (in some cases there's just as much space as without kerning).

I also read through the giant symbol archive but at a glance I couldn't find anything appropriate. Well, I didn't know what I'm looking for so maybe I missed it. Surely this type of notation is quite common?

Is there any better way to achieve this? Honestly I don't even know if an apostrophe is the right kind of dash for this kind of labeling. So any suggestions for coding magic or new symbols are welcome.

Many thanks.

Comment: For individual letters, you can use the kern, as in `A\kern-1.7pt'`.  Each letter will, in general, require a different kerning.  Something similar in math mode: `$\mathrm{A\!}'$`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{A}' \quad \mathrm{X}' \quad
 \mathrm{A}\!' \quad \mathrm{A}\mkern-2mu' $
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

the large gap between the A and the prime is because of the shape of the A.
if you have`\mathrm{X}'` the spacing is much nicer.
so "backing up" the prime is what is needed.  a negative thinspace, `\!`, is too much,
but `\mkern-2mu` may be just about right.  (a thin space = `3mu`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you do `A'` in text mode, you get an A followed by a single right quote (a separate symbol). Use math mode to attach a prime to a symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A' \quad $A'$
\end{document}
```

[image: Prime]

Comment: Thanks. The prime character looks good. Unfortunately math-ifying the whole thing also puts the A in italics which I'd rather avoid.  And when I un-math the A or the A' with something silly like $\mathrm{A}'$ or $\mbox{A'}$ the A straightens out again - and is as far away from the (beautiful) ' as ever. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @user38088 --- I think you will need to use negative spacing to get the prime closer to the A (TeX puts characters in rectangular boxes and you need the boxes to overlap). Can you add an example that shows how your use of `\kern` goes wrong?

Comment: @barbara-beeton's reply did the trick. Thanks for helping!